# Filling for Caribbean roti

Tags: caribbean-cuisine

Some years back my girlfriend visited Trinidad and Tobago, and there she encountered a dish that she just called roti. She used to buy it from a stand, which offered many variations. The one she favored was one with a spicy chicken filling.

Now rotis I know, or at least the Indian roti, which I presume this caribbean dish has its origin from. But the filling are more of a mystery. Are there typical chicken filling for rotis in Trinidad and Tobago? In that case does it have a name or some typical ingredients so I have a starting point in recreating this mystery dish?

Comment: They are based on indian roti; but ingredients in the fillings are slanted towards what's available in the Caribbean. Recipes abound with a quick search for caribbean roti.

Answer (score 1):

Like a lot of Caribbean cuisine (curries, rice and peas, chilli), these *are* based on the Indian equivalent, brought by indentured labourers from the sub-continent.

There's a recipe here: http://www.food.com/recipe/caribbean-trinidad-roti-288544 - generally fillings are vegatable-based and usually include sweet or regular potato, chickpeas and curry and chilli powder.

If you like them you may also enjoy Indian stuffed-parathas ([here's a recipe you can try](http://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/stuffedparathas_85439)) - the original and IMHO, the best ;-)

Comment: Great answer! Parathas are already a favourite of mine, yum yum.